# how to create Firestore composite index with parent document and child document?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create Firestore composite index with parent document and child document. but I dont know how to do this.

I can create composite index with different field. but it's not working with parent and child field.

Here is my database design:

[image: Database]

Comment: What do you mean through "create Firestore composite index with parent document"? What is the expected result?

Comment: Right now your question is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where Y isn't possible (see my answer below). You might want to describe what you're trying to accomplish with this solution so that we can help you find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

An index in Cloud Firestore works on a single collection. There is no way to create an index that spans multiple collections, not even when one of those collections is a subcollection of the other.